# Why am I getting generator has no len error on this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am following this tutorial

https://stackabuse.com/association-rule-mining-via-apriori-algorithm-in-python/

and am getting the following error when I run the below code.

I am honestly not sure what to try as I am following the tutorial verbatim.

I don't see what the issue is.

```
#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
from apyori import apriori
store_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\eyaze\\Downloads\\store_data.csv', header=None)

print(store_data.head())

records = []
for i in range(0, 7501):
    records.append([str(store_data.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])

association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.0045, min_confidence=0.2, min_lift=3, min_length=2)
association_results = list(association_rules)

print(len(association_rules))
```

I am expecting to get 48 as per the tutorial but I instead get the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very similar to this one I found on medium:
https://medium.com/@deepak.r.poojari/apriori-algorithm-in-python-recommendation-engine-5ba89bd1a6da

I guess you wanted to do `print(len(association_results))` instead of association_rules, as is done in the linked article?

Answer (score 0):

it's a generator, and it only point's to the first block of your code list, if u want to find length , then iterate over it first and then use length ie `print(len(list(association_rules)))`